# Calling functions from other functions in PHP

Tags: php, function

Hey so I got tired of writing

```
echo "varname message";
var_dump(variable);
```

So I wrote this

```
function debugger($var, $message) {
    echo $message;
    var_dump($var);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Which seems to work fine, except when its in a function. Then its like it doesn't know that there's a function defined, because its defined outside of the function. Like so.

```
function blah() {
    $x = 2;
    debugger($x, "this is x");
}
```

Also, I don't understand functions, I knew you cant reference something in a function outside of the function without returning it, but I didn't know you couldn't reference variables or functions outside of the function without setting them as parameters. I think I have this wrong though.

So one more thing, does that mean that the variables inside of a function don't conflict with the ones outside a function unless its returned?

Comment: Looks like my phone formatted it all as one line too. But thats not the problem

Comment: It would normally work, the problem is elsewhere. Functions (not class methods, but actual functions) have global scope, so they can be called everywhere....

Comment: At first look, I though the its [tag:C#]. What is your error message?

Comment: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/V72am1Wa) shows that the code above works.

Comment: Read up a little on scope - it'll answer your questions about what's accessible where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. Something else is wrong in your code. Try being more precise about what is not working and try isolating your problem. As for your other questions:

Variables defined in a function are scoped to that function, and will not interfere with variables from other functions. They also cannot access variables defined outside the function. For example

```
$a = 5;
function foo() {
    echo $a; //This will not work
}
```

What you can do is use the `global` keyword to "include" variables into your function's scope, if you don't want to pass them as arguments:

```
$a = 5;
function foo() {
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}
```

Or since a certain version of PHP (not sure which, if anyone knows please edit), you can use `use`:

```
$a = 5;
function foo() use ($a) {
    echo $a;
}
```